# Why did Kung Fu Chess shut down?

Tags: chess-variants

Kung Fu Chess, a chess variant in which there are no turns (everyone can move at once with a time delay for each piece), began in 2002 by Shizmoo games, and the website suddenly went offline in 2008 despite a large following and many proficient players.

Is the reason for their sudden demise known and are there present day alternatives to kung fu chess?

Comment: Any updates for real time Kung fu chess?! I miss that game. Most of the links above do not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No reason for Shizmoo's site closure in 2008 has been published online that I could find. There is a forum for former Kung Fu Chess enthusiasts here, but it's not particularly busy at the moment: http://www.zenchess.com/forum/

A few turnless/live chess variations inspired by Kung Fu Chess have sprung up, though, notably:

#### Ninja Chess for iPad

http://www.nordlysa.com/ninjachess/

Two players, iOS.

[image: Ninja Chess]

#### Real Time Chess

http://play.svenardo.com/chess/

One-player vs computer, [in-browser](http://play.svenardo.com/chess/), [iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/realtime-chess-new-chess-experience/id687203498?mt=8), [Mac](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7dwbq4aukgtsht/Realtime%20Chess.zip) and [Windows](https://mega.co.nz/#!1wdUiCQZ!LmVCHEoKTV25JnV2d3YAamssMXBgUWh2T-Hk5OvhYBw), where the first player to capture the king wins. Moved pieces cannot be moved again until their timer completes.

[image: Real Time chess game]

#### JebChess

http://jebchess.com/

A four-player live version.

[image: Jebchess]

Comment: This game sounds like a lot of fun!

Comment: I haven't played the other two, but [Real Time Chess](http://play.svenardo.com/chess/) is a little too easy on the default mode. As White, play 1. e4 2. Qh5 3. Bb5 and then capture the king as soon as one of the diagonals opens. It doesn't seem to use an engine, so it won't defend the attack. At increased speeds it's very tricky, though – it's hard to match the computer's speed, so you just get washed away by a wall of pawns.

Comment: I've heard this called "Tempest Chess" as well.

Answer (score 5):

I just launched a remake of Kung Fu Chess at https://www.kfchess.com/. Check it out and let me know what you think!

Answer (score 4):

judochess.com is the new tempest chess website, there are some highly skilled players but servers sometimes lag